# Does TestNG have a test collection functionality similar to pytest --collect-only with hooks?

Tags: java, testng, pytest

Pytest provides the ability to run pytest on a test repository using a `--collect-only` option that simply outputs the tests it finds based on current configurations.

Additionally, there are hooks that can be implemented that affect what happens during various phases of the collection, such as `pytest_collection_modifyitems`.

I'm wondering if there's an equivalent collection/hook system available for Java tests using TestNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG can be instructed to look for all `@Test` methods within a specific package and everything inside.

But by default, after TestNG discovers the tests, it executes them.

So in order for your use case to be done, you would need to do the following:

1. Create a testng suite xml file, that refers to the top level package `com.foo.bar` for e.g., wherein all the test classes are residing inside either `com.foo.bar` package or inside a sub-package.
2. Run TestNG with the JVM argument `-Dtestng.mode.dryrun=true` which causes TestNG to simulate as if the tests were run without actually running them.

Using both these two things, your use case should be satisfied.

Comment: Is it possible to hook into the process so that programmatic analysis on the “dry running” tests can be performed?

Comment: You can make use of TestNG listeners that work as callbacks to tap into events ( such as test about to start, test failed, test skipped, reporting etc). For more details pls refer to my blog post https://rationaleemotions.com/testng_listeners/